# currently my search bar is displaying in end of the menu(In last li)How to change search bar ordering in custom wordpress menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am using this code in my top menu (`function.php`). But through this code the search bar will display at the end of the menu (i.e. the last `li`).

How can I change the ordering? I have to place it in the first `li`. Is it possible or not?

```
/**
  * Add search box to primary menu
  */
function wpgood_nav_search($items, $args) {
  // If this isn't the primary menu, do nothing
  if( !($args->theme_location == 'topmenu') ) 
    return $items;
  // Otherwise, add search form
    return $items . '<li class="search-in-menu"><p id="hm-search1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></p>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpgood_nav_search', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Can you please show me the layout of the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

push it at front and return the value

```
/**
 * Add search box to primary menu
 */
function wpgood_nav_search($items, $args) {
    // If this isn't the primary menu, do nothing
    if( !($args->theme_location == 'topmenu') ) 
    return $items;
    // Otherwise, add search form
    return '<li class="search-in-menu"><p id="hm-search1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></p>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>'.$items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpgood_nav_search', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Which function?

Comment: change this line return '<li class="search-in-menu"><p id="hm-search1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></p>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>'.$items;

Comment: WORKED!!

Thank you!